# How to make onLocationChanged get called faster

Tags: android, google-play-services

I got this to work in my sample app:
http://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html

I get a new location with every callback to onLocationChanged.  However, the fastest I can observe it to refresh is around 1 second.  What can I do to make onLocationChanged get called more frequently?

In my Android Manifest, I use this:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

In my Java code, I use PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY:

```
mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
```

I also use set the Interval and FastestInterval to a below a second.

```
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(50);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(10);
```

But it's not not updating anywhere close to 50 or 10 millisecond.  I'm using an HTC One M8, which is fairly new hardware.

Any ideas on making Location Services sample much faster?  Thanks.

Comment: How fast are you going that <1 second GPS locations make a big difference?

Comment: It's for data capture.  I'd like to at least sample every 0.5 seconds.  Why take a parameter in milliseconds if it can't sample faster than a second?

Comment: @Gerard, did you resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

The docs for `LocationRequest.setInterval()` says:

> This method sets the rate in milliseconds at which your app prefers to receive location updates. If no other apps are receiving updates from Location Services, your app will receive updates at this rate.

The fact that you're not receiving calls to `onLocationChanged()` as frequent as you've stated must be because there are other apps receiving updates from Location Services.

I recommend you check if you have other apps utilizing Location Services and try closing them to see if you start receiving updates at your desired rate.